# Как правильно брать логарифм?

Tags: lisp, scheme

Пишу лабу на Scheme Lisp. Вариант:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
(define (fun z)
 (set! z (+(*(/(/ 103 104) e) (- 0 1)) z))
 (-(+(*(* 4 log(z)) log(z)) (* 6 log(z))) 5)
)
```

Ошибка:

> application: not a procedure;
>
> expected a procedure that can be
>
> applied to arguments
>
> given: 2.017623872397619
>
> arguments...: [none]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
( log   z)
```

`log` - это такая же функция, как сложение или вычитание